# Creating fast plumbing quotes with lists of equipment in excel - then turning into a word doc or PDF

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, macros

I would like to create a series of events that happen - to correspond with a drop down list in excel. These would be for example

Within a header 'plant room' in Excel you select a size and type of hot water cylinder from a list.

When selected a list of components is populated elsewhere - probably on another tab.
The same is done with the basic elements of bathrooms, showers, and radiators (design will vary, but basic valves, taps etc will be the same).

On another tab would appear a summary of the cost to the customer, including 15% mark up on parts and labour, which is also recorded as part of the cost for that job.

Once all the basics are in there, we would be able to amend and change elements, this information would then be easily exported to a nicely designed word doc including information on warranties, terms and conditions, compliance etc

I know some of this would be achieved with macros, but I don't know what terms to search for and I'm very much an amateur.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @DavidPostill FWIW, I was seconds away from finishing an answer that would be far more helpful to the poster and was mostly just a breakdown of how to go find each answer for themselves. I have moved the post to PasteBin instead since answers are now blocked: https://pastebin.com/98uy1gTJ

Comment: @DavidPostill To clarify, I saw this as a "How do I get started?" question instead of a "Please make this for me" question. I was trying to solve the question raised by `but I don't know what terms to search for`.

Comment: @EngineerToast I've reopened so you can answer.

Comment: Yes a quoting system is doable in excel, but it will depend on your comfort with excel. Beyond this ask, you should be looking at a "quote to cash" system which may better fulfill your long term needs. I think the market leader (in home service space) is Service King, but costs may not be to your liking. Good luck.

Comment: This would be similar to an Invoice. This sounds like a catalog/directory merge. See http://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/38721-microsoft-word-catalogue-directory-mailmerge-tutorial.html and http://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html. You may want to post this question in the Mail Merge forum (with a link to this cross-post). http://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/

Answer (score 0):

You've asked for where to start so I'll answer some of that. We can't create the entire file for you, but this may get you a little started and then you can come back with specific questions about one step of the process.

---

> Within a header 'plant room' in Excel you select a size and type of
> hot water cylinder from a list.

[How to make a drop-down list.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-drop-down-list-7693307a-59ef-400a-b769-c5402dce407b) (If that link rots, you can find similar instructions with a web-search, I'm sure.) I'd recommend a single list that combines both size and type into a single list ("40 gallon Gas") as opposed to one list for size and another for type. This will be easier to work with.

---

> When selected a list of components is populated elsewhere - probably
> on another tab. The same is done with the basic elements of bathrooms,
> showers, and radiators (design will vary, but basic valves, taps etc
> will be the same).

Macros can indeed be used to make something happen when a certain cell is changed. Here is one example of how to make this happen. This code would live in the sheet object (as opposed to the workbook object or in a module) and is triggered whenever any cell changes but only does something interesting when cell `A1` changes. Maybe search for "[getting started in vba](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office)" or something. You could also do this all with formulas by having all your pricing data in a big table and using `FILTER()` or something.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        ' Go do macros things because that special cell was changed
    End If
End Sub
```

You may want to consider having the user populate a whole list of things they want to price out and then pushing a button for the macro to run through that list and add the components / labor for each in a row. I would probably have that macro clear the list as it blows out each item to prevent the user from clicking the button twice by accident and adding everything *again*.

---

> On another tab would appear a summary of the cost to the customer,
> including 15% mark up on parts and labour, which is also recorded as
> part of the cost for that job.

You could probably do this with formulas if you were consistent in how you setup your data on the tab the macro changes. You could also bake this into the macro itself, if you prefer.

---

> Once all the basics are in there, we would be able to amend and change
> elements, this information would then be easily exported to a nicely
> designed word doc including information on warranties, terms and
> conditions, compliance etc

Word has its own VBA objects, methods, etc. That's a big question. [Here's the first hit](https://www.exceltip.com/import-and-export-in-vba/how-to-copy-data-from-excel-to-word-using-vba-excel.html) from my basic web search. Conceptually, I'd say you could start with a word file that has a nice header, your warranties, and anything else you like. Include a placeholder for each bit of data you want to copy from Excel. For instance, it could have the literal text `[TOTAL COST]`. The VBA in Excel would copy that file, open it for editing, and then find / replace the placeholder text with the value from the Excel file. This is just one idea.

---

Work on each piece one at a time. If you get stuck on a particular step, try to find your own solution, first. If you can't figure it out and can't figure out *why* you can't figure it out, come back and ask a